# Getting following error "Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [byte] for value" while fetching record from mongoDB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

I am facing a problem while fetching records from MongoDB. I am researching on StackOverflow for two days but could not find any solution for this error.
In MongoDB I use to store email attachment byte array while fetching the document getting converstionFailedException this does not happen for all the documents but some of the documents.
I tried to change the datatype from byte[] to string it worked but in response getting string as an output. My output should be byte[] as the file will be downloaded from the front-end.

```
    package com.maxxton.inbox.email;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Attachment implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private Integer attachmentId;

  private String attachmentName;

  private String attachmentType;

  private AccessType accessType;

  private byte[] content;

  public Integer getAttachmentId() {
    return attachmentId;
  }

  public void setAttachmentId(Integer attachmentId) {
    this.attachmentId = attachmentId;
  }

  public byte[] getContent() {
    return content;
  }

  public void setContent(byte[] content) {
    this.content = content;
  }

  public String getAttachmentName() {
    return attachmentName;
  }

  public void setAttachmentName(String attachmentName) {
    this.attachmentName = attachmentName;
  }

  public String getAttachmentType() {
    return attachmentType;
  }

  public void setAttachmentType(String attachmentType) {
    this.attachmentType = attachmentType;
  }

  public AccessType getAccessType() {
    return accessType;
  }

  public void setAccessType(AccessType accessType) {
    this.accessType = accessType;
  }

}
```

MongoTemplate code to fetch all the messages

```
    @Override
  public Page<Email> getAllMessagesWithDetail(Pageable pageable, MessageFilter messageFilter) {
    // Criteria finalCriteria = handleCriteria(messageFilter);
    Query query = new Query();
    Query queryWithPaging = query.with(pageable);
    applyMessagesSortBy(query, messageFilter);
    List<Email> messages = Objects.requireNonNull(mongoTemplate.find(queryWithPaging, Email.class).collectList().block());
    Long count = Objects.requireNonNull(mongoTemplate.count(query, Email.class).block());
    return new PageImpl<>(messages, pageable, count);
  }
```

Error which I received

```
{
"uniqueId": "c590d728-a8d8-4fe9-b0a7-c3904877f301",
"timestamp": "2022-01-25T06:04:52.963195400Z",
"errorCode": "GEN-900",
"message": "Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [byte] for value '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.....
```

Below screenshot on how attachment content is stored in mongoDB
[attachment content stored in mongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kND80.png)

Please let me know if anything else is required.
Thanks in advance to all who have viewed this Question.

Comment: The content looks base64 encoded, does it work if you use String type and manually [base64 decode](https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode) it?

Comment: some other options: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-mongodb-upload-file

Comment: Didn't get ur point. can u share a bit more info

Comment: one possibility is to change this `private byte[] content;` to `private String content;`.  Then call `byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(content);`

Comment: Out of 3.8lakh data only few of them where giving this error. I tried something like this Base64.decorder(content) from stackoverflow.

Comment: it sounds like invalid data